# Python mongoengine select_related(n) not doing what I expected

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have an object stored in mongo that has a list of reference fields. In a restplus app I need to parse this list of objects and map them into a JSON doc to return for a client.

```
# Classes I have saved in Mongo
class ThingWithList(Document):
    list_of_objects = ListField(ReferenceField(InfoHolder))

class InfoHolder(Document):
    thing_id = StringField()
    thing_i_care_about = ReferenceField(Info)

class Info(Document):
    name = StringField()
    foo = StringField()
    bar = StringField()
```

I am finding iterating through the list to be very slow. I guess because I am having to do another database query every time I dereference children of objects in the list.

Simple (but rubbish) method:

```
info_to_return = []    
thing = ThingWithList.get_from_id('thingsId')
for o in list_of_objects:
    info = {
        'id': o.id,
        'name': o.thing_i_care_about.name,
        'foo': o.thing_i_care_about.foo,
        'bar': o.thing_i_care_about.bar
    }
    info_to_return.append(info)
return(info_to_return)
```

I thought I would be able to solve this by using select_related which sounds like it should do the dereferencing for me N levels deep so that I only do one big mongo call rather than several per iteration. When I add

```
thing.select_related(3)
```

it seems to have no effect. Have I just misunderstood what this function is for. How else could I speed up my query?

Comment: first of all , could you provide the input document structure and which driver (language) are you using

Comment: I am using Python 3.6 with mongoengine 0.15.0